# Adding shadow to UIView that is positioned using SnapKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, snapkit

I have positioned a UIView using SnapKit and need to find a way to add a shadow. Because I positioned the view relative to other UIViews, I do not have the height, width, or starting coordinate of the view. How can I add a shadow to this UIView positioned using SnapKit auto layout. The code to position the UIView is this:

```
tableViewBackground.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()
        make.height.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()
        make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        make.top.equalTo(poiLabel.snp.bottom).offset(20)
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `layer` shadow settings, just like any other view shadow?

Comment: @matt I have tried using `tableViewBackground.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: tableViewBackground.bounds).cgPath`. The issue is `tableViewBackground.bounds` equals [0,0,0,0] because the view is positioned using snapkit

Comment: That merely suggests that you're doing it too soon. Wait until after the view _has_ been positioned so that you have actual bounds.

Comment: @matt thanks for the advice. Currently the shadow layer is added right after the Snap Kit constraints are set in the view controller method onViewDidLoad. Where should I add the shadow layer?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is probably the earliest reliable moment. But beware because it can be called many times subsequently.

Comment: @matt alright thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the creation of the shadow layer from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`